# Java Lists alternate for nested forEach

Tags: java

Below is my working code set of nested `forEach`. Looking for the best alternate to make code clean. Looks to be a very complex set of code

This `Model1` is a `List` containing various `SubList` and other few elements

```java
List<Model1> listModel1 = getDataForModel1(......);
listModel1.getSubList1().forEach(dataSubList1 -> {
    dataSubList1.getChildSublList2().forEach(dataChildSubList2 -> {
        dataChildSubList2.getChildSubList3().forEach(dataChildSubList3 -> {
          if (dataChildSubList3.getIsValid()) {
              // Setting my required data in this dataChildSubList3 all properties
            }
        })
    })
})
```

The above code is working as expected but Looking for an alternate to `forEach`. Thus making the above code less complex. Thanks in advance

Comment: Queston about optimizing working code should be asked at [codereview.SE]

Comment: We could use [`Stream::flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap(java.util.function.Function)) to flatten the inner lists down to the level we need.

Comment: would be very great @Turing85, if you can comment as an complete answer :) though i am trying what you said

Comment: @Ravi [There  you are](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70057671/4216641).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer should be seen as a sketch. Since the code does not explicitly define the return types, the code might not work 1:1.

---

In the following, I assume that:

- `listModel1.getSubList1()` returns a `List<Data1>`,
- `dataSubList1.getChildSublList2()` returns a `List<Data2>`, and
- `dataSubList2.getChildSublList3()` returns a `List<Data3>`.

---

If we use Java 8+, we can utilize the [`stream` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
List<Model1> listModel1 = getDataForModel1(......);
listModel1.getSubList1().stream()

    // 1st block replaces 1st foreach:
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)  // remove nulls, just to be safe
    .map(Data1::getChildSublList2) // transform each Data1-object to its list of 
                                   // Data2-objects
    .flatMap(List::stream) // flatten: transform each list in a stream of its 
                           // elements

    // 2nd block replaces 2nd foreach:
    .filter(Objects::nonNull) // remove nulls, just to be safe
    .map(Data2::getChildSublList3) // transform each Data2-object to its list of 
                                   // Data3-objects
    .flatMap(List::stream) // flatten: transform each list in a stream of its 
                           // elements

    // 3rd block replaces 3rd foreach:
    .filter(Objects::nonNull) // remove nulls, just to be safe
    .filter(Data3::getIsValid) // move if-condition to here
    .forEach(dataChildSubList3 -> {
        // Setting my required data in this dataChildSubList3 all properties
    });
```

It would be even better if we move the lambda-body of the `forEach`-lambda in a separate method (e.g. named `foo`) that takes a `Data3` as parameter and does the processing, this would simplify the `forEach(...)` to:

```
listModel1.getSubList1().stream()
    ...
    .forEach(this::foo);
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation :) Would be helpful for me, if i can get any reference link from you to master every aspect of spring-boot & microservices

Comment: The question has 0 to do with either spring-boot or microservices. I provided a link to the official documentation of the `stream` API for the constructs used in the answer. I myself am not an expert on spring-boot (I am more of a microprofile/quarkus guy), but the baeldung-tutorials are good. For microservices: google the term, get some opinions (the exact definition is most likely heavily opinionated) and then look for some book.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell by your original question if you need the lists on the top layer.
If all you need is the list of dataChildSubList3 you could do this:

```
List<Model1> listModel1 = getDataForModel1(......);
listModel1.getSubList1()
.stream()
.flatMap(dataSubList1 -> dataSubList1.getChildSublList2().stream())
.flatMap(dataSubList2 -> dataSubList2.getChildSublList3().stream())
.filter(dataSubList3::getIsValid)
.forEach(dataChildSubList3 -> {
          // Setting my required data in this dataChildSubList3 all 
    })
```

Comment: Instead of using an `if` within `forEach`, we should use `filter(...)` beforehand and then remove the `if` from the `forEach`-lambda. --- One could replace `.flatMap(dataSubList1 -> dataSubList1.getChildSublList2().stream())` with `.map(dataSubList1::getChildSubList2).flatMap(List::stream)` (some might find this easier to read).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, applied it to my response.